# Open PDF file and copy filepath and print pages VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, adobe

I currently have a macro that loops through a list and finds PDF files based on keywords. The macro works as it should, but I would like to take it a bit further. The macro searches for the correct PDF based on the report number per item.

I would like to loop and:

1. Hyperlink the file in the column "M".
2. Check if the file was opened correctly and place the status in column "K"
3. Minimize all open PDF windows.
4. If possible, find the Item number within the PDF and it's corresponding page. Each page is also bookmarked with the item number so it could be searched that way as well. I would like to somehow print the correct pages.

There are hundreds of reports and it is a very tedious process. I also have Adobe Pro. I am open to all suggestions.

Current working code to find PDF based on wildcard:

```
`Sub Open_PDF()
Dim filePath As String, fileName As String, iName As String
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To lrow
iName = Cells(i, 10)
FileType = Range("FileType")

filePath = Range("B6")
fileName = Dir(filePath & iName & "*" & "." & FileType)
If fileName <> "" Then
    openAnyFile filePath & fileName
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Function openAnyFile(strPath As String)
Dim objShell As Object
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.Open (strPath)
End Function
```

`

I found the following codes, but could not understand how to get it to work.

```
Option Explicit

'Retrieves a handle to the top-level window whose class name and window name match the 
specified strings.
'This function does not search child windows. This function does not perform a case- 
sensitive search.
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

`'Retrieves a handle to a window whose class name and window name match the specified 
strings.
'The function searches child windows, beginning with the one following the specified 
child window.
'This function does not perform a case-sensitive search.
Public Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

'Brings the thread that created the specified window into the foreground and activates 
the window.
'Keyboard input is directed to the window, and various visual cues are changed for the 
user.
'The system assigns a slightly higher priority to the thread that created the 
foreground
'window than it does to other threads.
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

'Sends the specified message to a window or windows. The SendMessage function calls 
the window procedure
'for the specified window and does not lParenturn until the window procedure has 
processed the message.
Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

'Places (posts) a message in the message queue associated with the thread that created 
the specified
'window and lParenturns without waiting for the thread to process the message.
Public Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "PostMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long)  
As Long

'Constants used in API functions.
Public Const WM_SETTEXT = &HC
Public Const VK_RETURN = &HD
Public Const WM_KEYDOWN = &H100

Private Sub OpenPDF(strPDFPath As String, strPageNumber As String, strZoomValue As String)

'Opens a PDF file to a specific page and with a specific zoom
'using Adobe Reader Or Adobe Professional.
'API functions are used to specify the necessary windows
'and send the page and zoom info to the Adobe window.

'By Christos Samaras
'https://myengineeringworld.net/////

Dim strPDFName                  As String
Dim lParent                     As Long
Dim lFirstChildWindow           As Long
Dim lSecondChildFirstWindow     As Long
Dim lSecondChildSecondWindow    As Long
Dim dtStartTime               As Date

'Check if the PDF path is correct.
If FileExists(strPDFPath) = False Then
    MsgBox "The PDF path is incorect!", vbCritical, "Wrong path"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Get the PDF file name from the full path.
On Error Resume Next
strPDFName = Mid(strPDFPath, InStrRev(strPDFPath, "") + 1, Len(strPDFPath))
On Error GoTo 0

'The following line depends on the apllication you are using.
'For Word:
'ThisDocument.FollowHyperlink strPDFPath, NewWindow:=True
'For Power Point:
'ActivePresentation.FollowHyperlink strPDFPath, NewWindow:=True
'Note that both Word & Power Point pop up a security window asking
'for access to the specified PDf file.
'For Access:
'Application.FollowHyperlink strPDFPath, NewWindow:=True
'For Excel:
ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink strPDFPath, NewWindow:=True
'Find the handle of the main/parent window.
dtStartTime = Now()
Do Until Now() > dtStartTime + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    lParent = 0
    DoEvents
    'For Adobe Reader.
    'lParent = FindWindow("AcrobatSDIWindow", strPDFName & " - Adobe Reader")
    'For Adobe Professional.
    lParent = FindWindow("AcrobatSDIWindow", strPDFName & " - Adobe Acrobat Pro")
    If lParent <> 0 Then Exit Do
Loop

If lParent <> 0 Then

    'Bring parent window to the foreground (above other windows).
    SetForegroundWindow (lParent)

    'Find the handle of the first child window.
    dtStartTime = Now()
    Do Until Now() > dtStartTime + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        lFirstChildWindow = 0
        DoEvents
        lFirstChildWindow = FindWindowEx(lParent, ByVal 0&, vbNullString, "AVUICommandWidget")
        If lFirstChildWindow <> 0 Then Exit Do
    Loop

    'Find the handles of the two subsequent windows.
    If lFirstChildWindow <> 0 Then
        dtStartTime = Now()
        Do Until Now() > dtStartTime + TimeValue("00:00:05")
            lSecondChildFirstWindow = 0
            DoEvents
            lSecondChildFirstWindow = FindWindowEx(lFirstChildWindow, ByVal 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
            If lSecondChildFirstWindow <> 0 Then Exit Do
        Loop

        If lSecondChildFirstWindow <> 0 Then

            'Send the zoom value to the corresponding window.
            SendMessage lSecondChildFirstWindow, WM_SETTEXT, 0&, ByVal strZoomValue
            PostMessage lSecondChildFirstWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0

            dtStartTime = Now()
            Do Until Now() > dtStartTime + TimeValue("00:00:05")
                lSecondChildSecondWindow = 0
                DoEvents
                'Notice the difference in syntax between lSecondChildSecondWindow and lSecondChildFirstWindow.
                'lSecondChildSecondWindow is the handle of the next child window after lSecondChildFirstWindow,
                'while both windows have as parent window the lFirstChildWindow.
                lSecondChildSecondWindow = FindWindowEx(lFirstChildWindow, lSecondChildFirstWindow, "Edit", vbNullString)
                If lSecondChildSecondWindow <> 0 Then Exit Do
            Loop
            If lSecondChildSecondWindow <> 0 Then

                'Send the page number to the corresponding window.
                SendMessage lSecondChildSecondWindow, WM_SETTEXT, 0&, ByVal strPageNumber
                PostMessage lSecondChildSecondWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0

            End If

        End If

    End If

End If

End Sub

Function FileExists(strFilePath As String) As Boolean

'Checks if a file exists.

'By Christos Samaras
'https://myengineeringworld.net/////

On Error Resume Next
If Not Dir(strFilePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileExists = True
On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Sub TestPDF()

OpenPDF ThisWorkbook.Path & "" & "Sample File.pdf", 6, 143

End Sub
```

Comment: why not close each pdf after it is opened / searched? You risk bogging down the system if you are opening a lot at once.

Comment: I am working on a code to close. I need to figure out how to search first.

Comment: To close, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714915/check-if-a-certain-pdf-file-is-open-and-close-it

Comment: To search, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192674/excel-vba-to-search-for-text-in-pdf-and-extract-and-name-pages

Answer (score 0):

I can partially help you:

```
Sub Open_PDF()
    Dim filePath As String, fileName As String, iName, disptxt As String
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To lrow
        iName = Cells(i, 10)
        FileType = Range("FileType")
        filePath = Range("B6")
        fileName = Dir(filePath & iName & "*" & "." & FileType)

        If fileName <> "" Then
            disptxt = filePath & iName ' whatever you want the hyperlink to show
            ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Range("M" & i), Address:=filePath & fileName, ScreenTip:="hover message", TextToDisplay:=disptxt
            Range("K" & i) = "Success"
            openAnyFile filePath & fileName
        Else
            Range("K" & i) = "Failed"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works, but I would like to link the actual file path as a hyperlink rather than create a new file name. The reason being is that it sometimes opens the wrong file, and I would like to visually check the name. Is that possible?

Comment: I've added in disptxt so you can define it easily :)